# Create object through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A user has_one avatar and an avatar belongs_to user. How should I create an avatar for a user? I could do this:

```
user #=> <# a user object >

Avatar.create(name: 'image', user_id: user.id)
```

But is there a better way? I thought maybe I could do this:

```
user.avatar.new(name: 'image')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`build_avatar`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-has-one-build-association-attributes) or [`create_avatar`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-has-one-create-association-attributes) like this:

```
user.build_avatar(name: 'image') # Instantiates avatar object
user.create_avatar(name: 'image') # Instantiates and saves to the database
```